How to calculate g-loading?
# install.packages("psych",repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
library(jsonlite)
library(psych)
data_matrix <- fromJSON("data.json")
tetra_corr <- tetrachoric(data_matrix)$rho
fa_result <- fa(r = tetra_corr, nfactors = 1, rotate = "varimax")
print(fa_result)

This gives me a list of per-item g-loadings, correct? How do I calculate the test's overall g-loading from this?
My JSON is an array of array of item responses where each response is either 0 or 1 (incorrect or correct).

If you only have one factor, you cannot rotate, so 'rotate = "varimax"' is redundant.

Do you mean g-loading in the IQ g-factor case? This is calculated when you have multiple first order factors. You only have one.

@JeremyMiles Yes. Can that be resolved by setting nfactors = 2?

Yeah, you can then rotate, but the number of factors should be determined separately from the rotation. In addition, the g-loading is usually from a second order factor analysis (or a principal components an analysis of different scale scores). If you use varimax rotation the correlation will be zero, so the g-loadings are all 0 (or one of them is 1 and the rest are zero; or they're not defined).
